# How to remove some text from url using Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have web page with vertical slider when i am running slider it is changing URL. I want to remove some text on page refresh. Like i have a URL 95.0.4.12/inner/innerpage3.html and when i am using slider it is changing this URL to inner/innerpage3.html#slide4 or whatever slider number

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
var top= window.top.location.href;
window.onload=$(document).scrollTop(0)
})
</script>
```

Comment: so what do you want to remove?

Comment: i want to remove #slide4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `document.location.hash` try the following:

> The `hash` property returns the anchor portion of a URL, including the hash sign (#).

```
$(function (){
    document.location.hash = ""
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.hash` to change the hash part of the URL. You can also use `document.referrer` to detect which slide the user came from.